# Android, полный путь до директории

Tags: java, android

Недавно начал изучать Android. Делаю приложение, которое удаляет файлы из своей корневой папки. Само приложение находится во внутренней памяти смартфона.

Всё работает, но есть один дилетантский вопрос.

Сейчас путь до нужной директории просто зашит в программу как литерал:

`/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.example.hello.testapk/files/Pictures`

Мне пришлось это сделать, потому что я не смог получить его методами.

Я пробовал:

```
Код -> результат

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() -> /storage/sdcard0
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() -> /storage/sdcard0
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName() -> /storage/sdcard0
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getCanonicalPath() -> /storage/sdcard0
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getParent() -> /storage

getFilesDir().getPath() -> /data/data/com.example.hello.testapk/files
getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() -> /data/data/com.example.hello.testapk/files
getFilesDir().getName() -> files
getFilesDir().getCanonicalPath() -> /data/data/com.example.hello.testapk/files
getFilesDir().getParent() -> /data/data/com.example.hello.testapk/files
```

Видно, что ни один из путей, ни любая его комбинация нужного пути не дают. Придётся парсить getFilesDir. Я уверен что это не правильно.

Дайте пожалуйста подсказку, как сделать правильно.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getExternalFilesDir()`
Вот вам список всех подобных функций
https://gist.github.com/granoeste/5574148